# Как перезагружать оператор в Python в зависимости от условия?

Tags: python, классы, атрибуты

Хотелось бы переопределять операторы типа `__eq__`, `__ne__` и т.п. в зависимости от передаваемого параметра. Пример:

```
mark = 1

class Class: 
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one  
        self.two = two

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.one == other.one
```

Как сделать так, что в зависимости от значения переменной mark сравнение происходило по соответствующему атрибуту (если mark == 1, то сравнение по one, если mark == 2, то сравнение по two)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какое условие вам нужно. Для примера, допустим, условие таково, что если поле `one` равно `None`, то сравниваем по `two`:

```
class Class: 
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one  
        self.two = two

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.one is None:
            return self.two == other.two
        else:
            return self.one == other.one
```

Есть довольно типичный случай, когда нужно по-разному сравнивать объект с объектами разных классов. Вот так это можно реализовать:

```
class Class: 
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one  
        self.two = two

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):  # Если сравниваем объект со строкой
            return self.one == other
        else:  # Сравнение с объектами любого другого класса
            return self.two == other
```

**Обновление.** Для условия "вне класса есть, допустим, переменная `mark`, и если `mark == 1`, то сравнение по `one`, а если `mark == 2`, то сравнение по `two`". Считаем, что `mark` - это просто глобальная переменная. Просто модифицируем первый вариант:

```
mark = 1

class Class: 
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one  
        self.two = two

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if mark == 1:
            return self.one == other.one
        else:
            return self.two == other.two
```

Однако, я не рекомендую вам делать так, что поведение объекта будет зависеть от какой-то внешней переменной. В крайнем случае можно сделать эту переменную атрибутом класса:

```
class SomeClass: 
    mark = 1

    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one  
        self.two = two

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self).mark == 1:
            return self.one == other.one
        else:
            return self.two == other.two

a = SomeClass(1, 'two')
b = SomeClass(1, 'three')

print(a == b)  # True

SomeClass.mark = 2

print(a == b)  # False
```

Comment: А если условие -- это содержание какой-то переменной вне класса? Например, вне класса есть, допустим, переменная mark, и если mark == 1, то сравнение по one, а если mark == 2, то сравнение по two.

Comment: Нет переопределение методов не позволяет изменить их сигнутуру. То есть == может быть только  __eq__(self, other) и никак иначе. Но вы можете через sys._getframe().f_back взять предпоследний фрейм и вытянуть из f_locals значение mark

Comment: @MariaObedkova, обновил ответ.

Comment: @AndrioSkur, не нужно переусложнять, Мария скорее всего имела в виду просто глобальную переменную. По поводу изменения сигнатуры я вообще не знаю где вы это увидели в вопросе.